# Creating a document every time someone signs up in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux-firestore

so am making a little  web Aplication and this is my first time trying to use firebase and React Js at the same time so my problem is am trying to make a document in fireStore every time a new User Signs up

```
// this is my SignUp Function 

  async function signUp(email, password,) {
     await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

/*and Im calling in it my component and as onSubmit Function and passing it the email and password 
and this is where things got me a little tricky because wheni tried to pass my CreateDocument Function as a callBack it throws me an error 

and this is my CreateDocument
 function   const creatProfileDocument = (currentuser) => {
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentuser.uid), {
      email: currentuser.email,
      age: false,
      name: "",
    })
  };*/
```

i Really hope someone can help me here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are generally two ways to go about this - immediately in your `signUp` code or via an auth trigger in Firebase Functions.

#### In Your Signup Code

You can create a document immediately after your async `signUp` function:

```
async function signUp(email, password) {
  // This function returns a credential which gives you the user's uid
  // which you could then use to create your document
  const credential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

  const uid = credential.user.uid

  // Create a new document using the uid as the document id
  // or however else you want to use this
  const ref = firebase.auth().collection("users").doc(uid)
  await ref.set({
    email,
    uid
  })
}
```

The good side of this is that you immediately create the document so you know it's there when your `signUp` function returns. The down side is that you have to loosen some security rules to allow users to create documents on this collection from the client. There are plenty of ways to keep it secure, but just be aware of this.

#### With Cloud Functions

Your `signUp` code creates a new auth record in Firebase, and Firebase has [Authentication trigger functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) that can fire when a new auth record is created or deleted.

```
exports.createUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // Your new auth record will have the uid and email on it because
  // you used email as the way to create the auth record
  return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
    email: user.email,
    uid: user.uid
  })
});
```

This is a secure way to handle things and doesn't require you to open up any security rules. But the drawback is that trigger functions are not guaranteed to fire immediately. They usually fire in a few seconds, but I've seen it take 30-60 seconds. So if your client-side code *needs* the document immediately on account creation, this is not a viable option.

Comment: What if the connection gets interrupted after creating the account but before creating the documents in Firestore? Is there a way to create something similar to a batch write that would somehow create an account at the same time as the documents are created, or are cloud functions the only other option?

Comment: A batch write would help you if you were concerned about some documents getting updated but others not in your network interrupted scenario, but wouldn't help in this case because the auth function and the document write are two separate function calls. You can't batch them. So if the network was interrupted between the calls, you're out of luck. But with cloud functions, you can enable retries which would help ensure that your function runs even if something happens to interrupt it. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries